# Перевод для Top Askers/Answerers

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, описание-метки

На странице участников по метке, например, [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/topusers), наблюдается несогласованность переводов:

> Top $tagLink$ Askers
>   Лучшие авторы вопросов $tagLink$

> Top $tagLink$ Answerers
>   Авторы лучших ответов по метке $tagLink$

По сути, задача - это правильно перевести слово "Top". Однако в данном случае нельзя утверждать, что автор или вопрос/ответ является "лучшим". Участники отсортированы по убыванию рейтинга (баллов) за сообщения.

Предлагайте ваши варианты в ответах.

Comment: Товарищи локализаторы, а есть ли возможность у пользователей ruSO включить английскую локализацию?

Comment: @vp_arth на первое апреля может быть (очень сомневаюсь) включат [советсткую](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4709/176217), а вот английскую вряд ли.

Comment: @vp_arth звучало бы забавно "Stack Overflow на русском на английском".

Comment: Почему? Тот же сайт, с русским контентом, но привычным, английским интерфейсом) Вполне логично, на мой взгляд. Но, не реализуемо, значит нет.

Comment: По теме: задача не только в `Top`. Куда делось `по метке` у авторов вопросов?

Comment: @vp_arth русский контент и английский интерфейс можно лицезреть местами на [rusSE](http://russian.stackexchange.com/). Отсутствие или наличие "по метке" это всё относится к проблемам перевода. Ответ на текущий вопрос должен решить и эту задачу.

Comment: "лучший" это хороший перевод для "top" в данном случае. Как "top" так и "лучший" можно по разным критериям определять. Как "top" так и "лучший" сами по себе не говорят по какому принципу сортировка происходит. Можно по количеству принятых ответов сортировать, который человек опубликовал за  рассматриваемый период, можно по количеству одобренных (положительные голоса или принятый) ответов, можно по общему балансу голосов за все ответы (что выбрать, зависит от конкретной задачи—нет "более правильной" в общем случае)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утвердил несколько изменённый [вариант](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4866/176217) @D-side:

> Top $tagLink$ Askers
>   Лучшие авторы вопросов с меткой $tagLink$

> Top $tagLink$ Answerers
>   Лучшие авторы ответов с меткой $tagLink$

Будет доступно после подкачки базы и сборки сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю совместить оба варианта и привести к общему виду:

> Top $tagLink$ Askers
>   Лучшие авторы вопросов по метке $tagLink$

> Top $tagLink$ Answerers
>   Лучшие авторы ответов по метке $tagLink$

---

#### Почему лучшие *авторы*?

> [...] нельзя утверждать, что автор или вопрос/ответ является "лучшим".

Вообще-то **можно** утверждать о лучших авторах. В контексте StackOverflow у этого понятия есть напрашивающееся (если не само по себе, то как минимум по таблице результатов) вполне конкретное определение.

"Лучший" в этом контексте — имеющий наибольшую сумму баллов по своим ответам к вопросам с конкретной меткой.

Утверждать же об авторстве *лучших ответов* действительно нельзя. Простой пример, показывающий разницу:

- Участник А с одним ответом на +10 (итого 10)
- Участник Б с десятком ответов на +2 каждый (итого 20)

С точки зрения данных в системе лучшим ответом из перечисленных является тот, что имеет рейтинг +10, однако его автор не занимает верхушку этого рейтинга.

#### Почему "по метке"?

Метки в именительном падеже и вклинить их в подобное короткое сообщение реально разве что в качестве названия к [дополнению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)). Любой другой падеж для метки рано или поздно приведёт к грамматическим аномалиям в интерфейсе. Ведь поскольку мы стремимся к русификации меток, у нас появятся (если ещё не появились) метки, склонение которых допустимо.

Поэтому лучше изначально построить грамматику фразы так, чтобы метка была в именительном. Других способов я сходу не вижу.

Comment: Т.е "Top" == "Лучшие"? Только в этом контексте или везде?

Comment: @alexolut это "верхние [в рейтинге]". Везде, где речь о рейтингах, это означает примерно "лучшие".

Comment: А если сделать "с меткой", разве это что-то усложнит? Именно так сейчас выглядит описание при просмотре [вопросов с меткой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/info).

Answer (score -3):

Ну так и переведи как "топовые".

Comment: [Надо кое-кого убедить](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3126/top-questions-and-answers-%d0%9b%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b#comment15583_4495)

Comment: @alexolut, "топ" != "топовый" ;)

Comment: Я не знаю как сравнивает Николай. Может только по первым трём буквам :)