# На странице метки не сходятся термины

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, описание-метки

На [странице метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/info) не сходятся термины:

1. Не компания, а метка
2. Не ответы, а участники

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Ого, кто-то нахулюганил?

Comment: ООО «Матрицы» :-D

Comment: @АндрейNOP причём аж 4 месяца назад, но, видимо, не обновлялась строка на одном из этапов.

Comment: @Юрий проблема ещё имеет место быть!

Comment: @älёxölüt, хм... Я среагировал на тревогу с просьбой `статус-завершено` поставить... Уберу)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб наказать флагальщика по всей SтрОгости! И модератора безответственного :)

Comment: @älёxölüt, мне кажется это недостаточная причина для начала [meta-tag:модераторский-произвол])

Comment: Во чего [откопал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2593/176217).

Comment: @älёxölüt, отлично, а фикс когда?

Comment: Так @Suvitruf запостил баг-репорт на MSE. Пока его не починят нормального "about" не ждите.

Comment: @älёxölüt а были случаи, когда они после таких реквестов разделяли ключи?

Comment: @Suvitruf [было](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305667/339911).

Comment: Почему [завершено]? Проблема до сих пор наблюдается. @ЮрийСПб передал эстафету? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, видимо была тревога с просьбой поставить метку... Что-то очень часто возникает ситуация с такой тревогой и выяснением, что ничего не завершено(

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я не в ту строчку посмотрел ((

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, неа, не было тревоги, я сам))

Comment: @Qwertiy, а, ОК)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Разделили строки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316766/260198). Теперь есть две разные строки: "О компании", "О метке".
2. Строка: `ca6d49252da56178c84d37f36e945dea`.

   Предложил старый вариант перевода:

   > Авторы лучших ответов

Comment: «Лучшие авторы» это еще не «лучшие ответы». См.[тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5384/176217)

Comment: @alexolut эм? https://web.archive.org/web/20161210031736/http://ru.stackoverflow.com:80/tags/php/info это тот перевод, что был раньше

Comment: Старое — не значит правильное :)

Comment: @alexolut лучше, чем ничего. Потом можно будет отдельный тред создать с голосованием по вариантам.