# Участник - это не метка

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора

На странице "Contact Community Team about" к участнику применился перевод от метки:

> [image: скриншот]

PS: Сначала я подумал, что это [компанию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8064/178988) так пофиксили, но нет - там по-прежнему неверно.

Comment: Не вижу такой страницы. Пока.

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну ты ж не модератор. Но с этим "about" надо бы разобраться...

Comment: @Qwertiy через пару лет пофиксят с выкаткой нового дизайна.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://ru.traducir.win/string/2770?

Comment: @Suvitruf [сомнительно всё это без контекста явного.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA3OV.png)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я там азапрувил предложение Квертия. Посмотрим, что это сломает. Потом откатим, если что)

Comment: @Suvitruf через пару суток минимум видно будет

Comment: @αλεχολυτ (: может раньше, если в мастер что-нить выкатят.

Comment: @Suvitruf для этого надо что-то серьёзное сломать :)

Comment: @Suvitruf пока контексты не разделят, всегда будет где-то косяк в переводах. Либо тут, либо там. Можно только по популярности (частоте видимости) выбрать если.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а вы на MSE про **about** тему поднимали?

Comment: @Suvitruf [ага](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316766/339911). Только там у меня ник другой :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это частный случай. Вообще, нужна возможность посмотреть список страниц, где ключик юзается.

Comment: @Suvitruf у КМ есть тул. Он хвастался как-то в чате.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ апдейт прилетел.