# "о метке" на странице связи с командой сообщества по поводу участника

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора

В диалоге по поводу мёрджа аккаунтов есть текст "о метке" напротив аватарки участника.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В традусёре такой строки не нашёл. Интересно, откуда она берётся.

Есть такая строка именно про метку:

https://ru.traducir.win/string/8836

Но там, во-первых, **О** большая. А во-вторых, в оригинале **Tag Info**, так что вряд ли она используется.

**UPD:** вот эта строка: https://ru.traducir.win/string/2770, перевод строки **about**.

Comment: `<td>о&nbsp;метке</td>` - вроде у нас нечасто неразрывные пробелы в локализации?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8423/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy вот строка https://ru.traducir.win/string/2770

Comment: Предложил перевод.

Comment: @Qwertiy нужно понять, не используется ли где-то ещё =/

Comment: Чтобы это понять, сначала там сломать надо))

Comment: @Qwertiy ну ок, утвердил. Посмотрим, поехало ли где-то.

Comment: Тут ещё на "из" стоит обратить внимание. Тоже нужно разделение контекстов.

Comment: @Qwertiy прилетел апдейт. Смотрим, где сломалось :D