# В профиле участников написано "О метке"

Tags: дефект, локализация

В профилях вместо "Об участнике" написано "О метке."

Похожий вопрос, но не о профиле: [Участник - это не метка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8423/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да! Я искал на "о метке" и ничего не нашлось, хотя помнил, что вроде уже было такое :)

Comment: Поэтому и нужны дубликаты, чтобы можно было находить по разным словам и формулировкам.

Comment: О, автор может тоже проголосовать за закрытие своего вопроса.