# На странице метки слетел перевод вкладки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, описание-метки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хвосты зачищали: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325568/339911 еще бы «компанию» жаваскрипта пофиксить

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8064/176217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод [добавил](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11888) по прежнему варианту:

> Сводка

Обновление доступно на сайте.