# Ошибки перевода в описание меток и англ. текст в конкурсах

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

В подробном описании метки ([любой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info)), пишет "О компании [метка]"

[image: Err1]

Также некоторые конкурсные вопросы стали говорить по английски ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1099730/220553)):

[image: Err2]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8064/178988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Разделили строки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316766/260198). Теперь есть две разные строки: "О компании", "О метке".
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14266. Добавил перевод:

> $bountyStarterLink$ хочет получить **канонический ответ**:

Появится после обновления движка.

Comment: По первому пункту предлагаю откатить перевод. Лучше никакого перевода не иметь, что впадать в заблуждение из-за ошибок в строках.

Comment: @mymedia к чему откатить?

Comment: стоит просто оставить строку без перевода - About